# Setting timezones

Tags: arch-linux, timezone

I want to set my timezone to America/New_York. date says that the current time is CEST. I'm using systemd, no desktop environment.

Right now I have

```
/etc/localtime links to /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York
/etc/timezone set to "America/New_York"
/etc/rc.conf set to "America/New_York" (arch linux should be ignored by systemd)
$TZ is unset
```

Hardware clock is set to utc time and works fine.

```
TZ=utc date
```

gives the right output.

Unfortunately I'm still on CEST. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York` has incorrect content.

Try issuing `zdump America/New_York` or `TZ=America/New_York date`

Comment: `[root@jupiter etc]# zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York 
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York  Tue Jul  3 19:20:40 2012 CEST`
Seems you're right ...

Comment: And I fixed it by re-installing tzdata. No idea how this could have happened. A corrupt file was the last thing I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @McEnroe, That's why I would advice against symlinking to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`. Actually, previously there was also such a reason due to problems with separate `/usr` partition layout making the link dangling until it got mounted finally during boot. Another one, as your issue shows is overwriting `/etc/localtime` would muck up original file as well. So, it's better to `cp` not `ln`…